# in R, recode a categorical variable as numeric and return to categorical

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data frame containing categorical variables, some with many unique values.
I would like to recode them as numeric, according to frequency (from rare to frequent), and later ( after I have performed some calculation) to go back to the original values.

For example,

```
df = tibble(x = c(rep("A", 10), rep("B", 15), rep("C", 23), rep("D", 40)))
df1 = df %>% group_by(x) %>% mutate(x_new = cur_grp_id())
```

This gives the original numeric recoding. Now I'd like to perform the opposite task (take into account there can be many unique values so I imagine the solution has to be vectoric and not based on case)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't imagine a use case where this would be useful but this should be a way to do it:

```r
x <- c(rep("A", 10), rep("B", 40), rep("C", 23), rep("D", 15))

# convert to factor according to frequency
x_fct <- factor(x) |> 
  forcats::fct_infreq()

# factors are integers under the hood
x_int <- as.integer(x_fct)

# convert back using same levels
factor(
  x_int, 
  levels = seq_along(levels(x_fct)),
  labels = levels(x_fct)
)
#>  [1] A A A A A A A A A A B B B B B B B B B B B B B B B B B B B B B B B B B B B B
#> [39] B B B B B B B B B B B B C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C D D D
#> [77] D D D D D D D D D D D D
#> Levels: B C D A
```

<sup>Created on 2023-10-21 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>